# Collapsing overlapping dates in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm downloading tweets from the Twitter API and I need to remove overlapping dates so that I don't request duplicate tweets that will eat up my monthly download quota. My data is in a pandas dataframe. Here is a sample of what I have and what I want to do in Python (or SQL), but I have no idea how to even tackle this. In SAS I could use a retain statement, but I don't think that's an option in python. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

df have:

| User | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 01-01-20 | 03-31-20 |
| User1 | 02-01-20 | 04-30-20 |
| User1 | 10-01-20 | 12-30-20 |
| User2 | 06-01-20 | 08-31-20 |
| User2 | 07-15-20 | 12-31-20 |
| User2 | 02-01-20 | 04-30-20 |

df want:

| User | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 01-01-20 | 04-30-20 |
| User1 | 10-01-20 | 12-30-20 |
| User2 | 02-01-20 | 04-30-20 |
| User2 | 06-01-20 | 12-31-20 |

Comment: There is no Apr 31, should the date `04-31-20` be `04-30-20` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.GroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to aggregate the overlapping date ranges, as follows:

```
# convert dates to datetime format
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], format='%m-%d-%y')
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format='%m-%d-%y')

# sort by columns User and start 
df = df.sort_values(['User', 'start'])

# set group number of overlapping date ranges within the same user
g = df['start'].gt(df['end'].shift()).groupby(df['User']).cumsum()

# Aggregate the overlapping dates
df_out = df.groupby(['User', g], as_index=False).agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'})
```

**Result:**

(With amendment of the invalid date `04-31-20` to `04-30-20` in the input data):

```
print(df_out)

    User      start        end
0  User1 2020-01-01 2020-04-30
1  User1 2020-10-01 2020-12-30
2  User2 2020-02-01 2020-04-30
3  User2 2020-06-01 2020-12-31
```

Optionally, you can also convert back the date format, as follows:

```
df_out['start'] = df_out['start'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%y')
df_out['end'] = df_out['end'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%y')

print(df_out)

    User     start       end
0  User1  01-01-20  04-30-20
1  User1  10-01-20  12-30-20
2  User2  02-01-20  04-30-20
3  User2  06-01-20  12-31-20
```

Comment: @mailynf  Pleased to help!   Happy programming!  :-)